# Netlify function with basic authentication

Tags: netlify

I have a Netlify function that will work like a cronjob. I will trigger it through GitHub Actions. At the moment anyone who knows the url can trigger the cronjob. The url can in theory be spammed by a bot, so I want to add basic authentication on this url. I found that following setup must work, but it doesn't. After deploy the url is still publicly available and no authentication is required.

I created a _headers file:

```
/.netlify/functions/function1
  Basic-Auth: username:password
```

```
#netlify.toml
[build]
command = “yarn build && cp _headers public/_headers”
functions = “functions”
publish = “public”
```

During deploying I can see it’s picking this up:

```
2:38:08 PM: ┌────────────────────────────────────┐
2:38:08 PM: │ 2. build.command from netlify.toml │
2:38:08 PM: └────────────────────────────────────┘
2:38:08 PM: $ yarn build && cp _headers public/_headers
```

After the deploy has finished and I download the deploy, I can see the _headers file. It’s equal to my local (dev) file.

However, with all this, when surfing to “app.netlify.app/.netlify/functions/function1” the page does not request a username and password and the page behaves like no authentication is present.

I followed examples like:

1. https://docs.netlify.com/visitor-access/password-protection/#site-wide-protection
2. https://goulet.dev/posts/how-to-password-protect-staging-on-netlify/

Does anyone know what might be missing in my setup?

Thanks